# Python OpenOPC Read Failed

Tags: python, open-opc

when i try to connect with OPC, the status is a success but my kernels restarted when i try to read tag value. try debug and it shows the above file "Reloaded modules: win32com.gen_py.341A7851-5DEA-4022-B0D6-F9954AF9273Dx0x1x0" how do i solve this

- Spyder version: 5.5.1  (conda)
- Python version: 3.10.13 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.15.2
- PyQt5 version: 5.15.10
- Operating System: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
- OpenOPC-DA 1.5.0

i try to :

1. update pywin32 (failed)
2. simulate and installed bit32 version (failed)
3. update spyder version

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.